# How to present a modalView just above the control which makes it pop up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

[image]

How can I create a modal to pop up just above the button clicked?

As shown here above in the image, the pop up is just above the button "sleeping like a baby".

I want the modal to pop up in a similar way.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by changing the frame of your popup view with animation as -

```
[popUpView setFrame:];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[popUpView setFrame:];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: So `PopUpView` should just be a UIView in same ViewController? Or should it be a seperate ViewController?

Comment: It can be both but i will prefer UIView in same class.

Comment: Ok fine. Thanks I will try that out and get back to you